# Configuring Codeblocks for GTK+

Tags: configuration, gtk, codeblocks

I have configured CodeBlocks with lib , src, bin , include paths for GTK+ , and I have choosen the GTK+ project

I am trying to run the program in http://pastebin.org/366972

But during build I am getting errors - please see http://pastebin.org/366980 .

Am I missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the GTK+ libraries to the linker and other dependencies:

- gtk-win32-2.0.lib
- gdk-win32-2.0.lib
- atk-1.0.lib
- gdk_pixbuf-2.0.lib
- pangowin32-1.0.lib
- pango-1.0.lib
- gobject-2.0.lib
- gmodule-2.0.lib
- glib-2.0.lib
- intl.lib
- iconv.lib
- glade-2.0.lib
- xml2.lib

Under Linux, which libraries are needed would be returned by the command: `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs`.

Comment: I could not these in the lib - iconv.lib, glade-2.0.lib, xml2.lib. 
I did not download Glade - just wanted to start with a simple program. However, even after adding the libs to the linker option , I am still getting the errors  - http://pastebin.org/380778

Comment: What compiler are you using? It could also be due to a mismatching calling convention in the linker settings, I think it should be cdecl, maybe it is tuned to something else.

Comment: I was using mingw compiler which came along with Codeblocks.Would you mind sending you contact details to softwr-development[at]yahoo[dot]com. I removed the codeblocks generated program and executed the program at http://pastebin.org/388327 .. It worked fine. BTW I found all the libraries you have mentioned when I installed Glade with GTK+ . What would the setup if I want to install only GTK+ and Glib.